# autotranslate content in every enabled language with triggers autopublishes the new content in drupal

Tags: drupal, cck, publish, translate

I have a rule in triggers in drupal that when I create a new content it auto translates the new created content into every enabled language.. that's ok with a couple of problems (like Drupal always prooves to be)

it publishes the new translated content, even if I don't publish my original content..

that would be ok if .. I could even copy the uploaded image from CCK or even tell to translate CCK content...

I couldn't pass to the translation the added CCK fields, so only the title and the body cotent are being translated..

How could I pass cck fields also and tell it NOT to publish in specific..

I could even use php code and program something, but I don't know where to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to dive into PHP: Look at the module which provides the translation action and make it more clever. Very likely the module maintainer would be happy about such a contribution.

The rules documentation at http://drupal.org/node/298476 isn't complete, but gives you a start. I found id helpful to look at other modules rules implementations.